# received an error while trying to backup through admin

Tags: magento-1.9

When going to Admin>System>Tools>Backups, the following error gets generated:

```
There has been an error processing your request 
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons. 
Error log record number: 1295409723488
```

I have looked at the report, var/report/1295409723488 and it doesn't make any sense to me. It talks about Item **(Varien_Object) with the same id "2015_db" already exist"**. Is this in a database table?

I used to use Admin>System>Tools>Backups to get all database backups, but it was recommended NOT to use Magento's backups and perform database backups through SSH instead. So I moved all my previous backups to a folder called "Older_Backups" under var/backups (via ftp), to move them later on to my local storage.

Now when I go to Admin>System>Tools>Backups it displays the above error.

Error log record number: 1295409723488 displays about 36 lines.
Here is the trace:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:61:"Item (Varien_Object) with the same id "2015_db" already exist";i:1;s:5017:"#0 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Filesystem.php(307): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Varien_Object))
#1 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(622): Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem->loadData(false, false)
#2 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection->load()
#3 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Backup/Grid.php(51): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#4 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Backup_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#5 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#6 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#7 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('backupsGrid', true)
#9 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Backup.php(104): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('backupsGrid')
#10 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/list.phtml(39): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Backup->getGridHtml()
#11 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/abcd/...')
#12 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#13 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#18 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#20 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#21 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/abcd/...')
#22 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#23 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#24 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/BackupController.php(56): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_BackupController->indexAction()
#30 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#31 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#32 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#33 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#34 /home/abcd/public_html/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#35 {main}";s:3:"url";s:100:"/magento/index.php/admin/system_backup/index/key/13d5460bf336e3f689fc5a0e88/";s:11:"script_name";s:26:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

var/log/system.log, display's the following.

```
2015-07-03T16:26:57+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered  in /home/abcd/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 492
2015-07-03T16:26:57+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered  in /home/abcd/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 513
2015-07-03T16:27:04+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered  in /home/abcd/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 492
2015-07-03T16:27:04+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered  in /home/abcd/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 513
2015-07-03T16:27:04+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered  in /home/abcd/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 492
2015-07-03T16:27:04+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered  in /home/abcd/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 513
2015-07-03T16:27:04+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered  in /home/abcd/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 492
2015-07-03T16:27:04+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered  in /home/abcd/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 513
```

I did delete all cache, but I'm getting the same error. Otherwise everything else seems to functions properly. What could be causing this?

Comment: Ok I found out what causes the error: **(Varien_Object) with the same id "2015_db" already exist"**.This error is caused by the **name** of the backup files! My cron job generated two backup files. The file names started with -%p%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.Generating  backup files, similar to -20150705-11:30:15.gz and -20150705-23:30:15.gz. When going to Admin>System>Tools>Backups after the second backup is generated, it sees the first **n** characters of the backup names as the same ( -20150705). Hence throwing the error: **"-2015070606_db" already exist"**. I am trying to find the best way to name them.

Comment: The other issue I noticed is the **date** on the server for backup files are correct 7/5/2015, but in Admin>System>Tools>Backups the date is shown as some off date in 1900s (**Dec 31, 1969 4:00:00 PM**) Can not figure that now.

Comment: Magento uses the Unix/Linux timestamp for the file name prefix.