# Error message in system.log regarding non well formed numeric value in Gd2.php

Tags: magento-1.9, error-log, system.log, gd2

I can't figure out what this error message is in the system.log file. Have open the Gd2.php file looking at lines 492 and 513 and it has something to do with image watermark?

> 2015-08-15T20:24:41+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered  in /home/.../magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 492
>   2015-08-15T20:24:41+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered  in /home/.../magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 513

p.s. The files is getting very large with the same two lines above! It's about 119116 records.

Comment: Were you in backup in admin? This post has the same error, maybe it could help http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73205/received-an-error-while-trying-to-backup-through-admin

Comment: @kaska thanks for the link.  No I was not in admin>backup.  Looking at the log for today's date 2015/07/24; it created error `ERR (3): Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered` at the following times:  `2015-07-24T00:26`, `2015-07-24T01:08`, `2015-07-24T02:06`, `2015-07-24T03:19` and last one at `2015-07-24T05:07`.  These errors were generated after midnight, when admin was not used!

Comment: This doesn't happen while backing up in admin. I use the host cron to backup the database, and not admin!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove % from 'Image Watermark Opacity, Percent'.
Just put in a number, like 15.

Comment: Solved. After about 4.5 months you solved it for me in 2 seconds. The system log file size grew to 300-350 MB every other week!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your

```
[MAGENTO_ROOT_DIR]/app/design/frontend/default/etc/view.xml
```

for space between or after the numerical values, If any please remove them.