# Error message can't save a product

Tags: error, product-images, upload, gd2

I can't save any product the system is keep on giving me this message

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/.../magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 344
```

Please I need your help to solve this issue, it's about a month i'm looking for a solution.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75602/error-message-in-system-log-regarding-non-well-formed-numeric-value-in-gd2-php

Comment: What file do i modify here "Remove % from 'Image Watermark Opacity, Percent'. Just put in a number, like 15"

Comment: check here https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-image-watermarks.html